# WordPress CSS Menus & Text Alignment Issues

Tags: css, wordpress, alignment, menuitem, mousehover

I'm having a problem with the header menus, my sub-menus, and text alignment. Every time I hover my mouse over them, the word disappear. I want it to look like the About Us button when I hover the mouse over it then it turn black with the gold text. I tried using the same code for the header menus, but that disappearing effects didn't go away and it doesn't turn black when hover over it. I want to make the header menus and sub-menus to have the same effect as the About Us button when I hover over it. I want the picture and text in the About Us page to be at the center. I tried various padding and margin alignment methods, but it didn't work. Please help, and thank you. My website: http://www.empirenailsbar.com

Answer (score 0):

For your menu items which disapper You need to add in your style sheet the property for your menu item on hover:

```
#mainnav ul li a:hover{
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

This in this css file:

```
wp-content/themes/sydney/style.css?ver=4.4
```